# ArrayList not working in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created this AsyncTask that is not properly working in `doInBackground`. To better understand, I am pointing out some things:

1. `getFunctionVal(String function, double Val);` this method returns the value of a function calculated in a point (Ex.: `getFunctionVal("x+3", 2.0)` = 5.0).
2. `funzione` and `derivata` are two strings (they are equations).

**Problem**: I cannot understand why `soluzioni.size()` is always 0, and the same thing happens with `risultati.size()`. This didn't happen when I had this code inside a `OnClickListener` in the UI.

```
  public double b = -20;
  public double a = -20;

  public class TaskAsincrono extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View view;
    public List<Double> risultati = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Double> soluzioni = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public TaskAsincrono (Context context, View v){
        mContext = context;
        view = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
      dialog = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(), "", "Attendi...", false, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void[] values) {

    };

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        int step = 500;
        double k = (b-a)/step;

        List<Double> valoriIntervallo = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> valoriFunzione = new ArrayList<>();

        //Generates number for intervals
        for(int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
            double ak = a + k;
            double fak = getFunctionVal(funzione, ak);
            a += k;
            valoriIntervallo.add(ak);
            valoriFunzione.add(fak);
        }

        //show the number intervals
        for(int j = 0; j < valoriIntervallo.size()-1; j++) {

            if (Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j)) != Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j+1))) {
                risultati.add(valoriIntervallo.get(j));
                risultati.add(valoriIntervallo.get(j+1));
            }

        }

            k = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < (risultati.size()); i += 2) {

                k++;
                double a = risultati.get(i);
                double b = risultati.get(i + 1);
                double res = (b + a) / 2;

                for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                    res = res - (getFunctionVal(funzione, res) / getFunctionVal(derivata, res));
                }

                soluzioni.add(res);

            }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if(dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); }

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutTangenti);

        for (int o = 0; o < 1; o++) {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(mContext);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView coefficente = new TextView(mContext);
            coefficente.setText("x" + String.valueOf((o+1)) + " = ");
            coefficente.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            coefficente.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f));

            EditText decimale = new EditText(mContext);
            decimale.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            decimale.setText(String.valueOf(risultati.size()));
            decimale.setFocusable(false);
            decimale.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            decimale.setClickable(false);
            decimale.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.8f));

            tr.addView(coefficente);
            tr.addView(decimale);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }
}
```

If you are asking why I am using an AsyncTask, it's because I need to have `step = 50000` and I cannot "stress" the UI so much.

Comment: Why does this need to be in an AsyncTask? What does `getFunctionVal` do that requires it to be in a background thread?

Comment: Are you sure the steps variable isn't 0? I was following the logic and that was the most logical conclusion I came up with

Comment: This is not meant as an offense or to be a smarta**, but using english in your code would greatly improve the readability for everyone who doesn't speak italian.

Comment: @AdamRatzman Not sure about that... `int step = 500;`... `for(int i = 0; i < step;` ...

Comment: @AdamRatzman No I set the variable, it cannot be zero

Comment: @DK64 sorry, I meant to ask whether the function getFunctionVal just is returning 0 each time.. I misunderstood 

Comment: @AdamRatzman ah ok! :) no no, I have checked 4 times and getFunctionVal is correct and gives me something different from 0

Comment: @DK64 hmm, let me think

Comment: Ok, there's something about this IF statement that might be always returning false.  if (Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j)) != Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j+1))) {                 risultati.add(valoriIntervallo.get(j));                 risultati.add(valoriIntervallo.get(j+1));             }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` is 0. `funzione` is constant. Assuming `getFunctionVal` is a pure function, `valoriFunzione` contains 500 times the same value.

Which means that `Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j)) != Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j+1))` is always false.

Which is why there is nothing in `risultati`.

Comment: Yes, that was what I have noticed right now. I have to fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

Check that the the condition **if (Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j)) != Math.signum(valoriFunzione.get(j+1)))** evaluates to true.

Comment: Ayy lmao when we come up with the same answer at the same time

Comment: Yes I have just solved the issue :) the problem was there! Thank you both guys